# 424 code and graph creation in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA - tend to just go with stuff that works even if I don't understand it I'm afraid!

I'm trying to produce individual scatter graphs for each row of data from a worksheet. I'm OK with configuring the graph etc, but getting it to read each row and iterate properly is beyond me!

This is what I've got currently:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To WS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
    'Data?
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Progress"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet2!$B$1:$J$1"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet2!$B$" & i & ":$J$" & i

    'Titles
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "valuefromcellN2?"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Timeline"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Grade"
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

    'Formatting
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .HasLegend = False

End With
Next
End Sub
```

When I run this, I get a runtime error 424 - object required. My questions are:

1. Am I going about this in roughly the right way?
2. What have I missed out to cause this runtime error?
3. How do I get the **valuefromcellN2?** to actually show the value, not text?

Thanks for any help!

Sam

EDIT:

thanks for the help - I think I've updated it correctly now (it works with all titles and creates new graphs!)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = tracker
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Charts.Add
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
    'Data?
    .ChartType = xlXYScatter
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Progress"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=tracker!$B$1:$J$1"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=tracker!$B$" & i & ":$J$" & i

    'Titles
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Range("N" & i).Value
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Timeline"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Grade"
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

    'Formatting
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .HasLegend = False

End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are getting that error because you have not declared the `ws` object

Comment: `How do I get the valuefromcellN2? to actually show the value, not text?` Use this `.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Range("N2").Value`

Comment: Let me post a proper reply.. gimme few mins.

Comment: "tend to just go with stuff that works even if I don't understand it" That's a really bad idea. I can easily post an answer below that erases all files on your C:\ drive XD

Comment: findwindow you are right, and that is one of the reasons why I am trying to find the reason behind each of my questions.

Comment: Also, although I said I just go with stuff that works, I can still work out if it's in the right 'general' direction - I hope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1 Am I going about this in roughly the right way?

Yes you are. You need to just iron out few issues.

> Q2 What have I missed out to cause this runtime error?

You are getting that error because you have not declared the `ws` object. I have explained it later in the code below on how to go about it.

> Q3 How do I get the valuefromcellN2? to actually show the value, not text?

To get the value from a particular cell, you can say `Range("A1").Value` so in your case it will be `Range("N2").Value`

**Few other things**

1. When working with Excel rows, avoid the use of `Integer`. Use `Long`. Post Excel 2007, the number of rows have increased and the `Integer` may not be able to accommodate bigger values.
2. Avoid using hard coded values like `65536`. See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) on how to find the last row.

**Code**

I have commented the code so you shouldn't have a problem understanding it. But if you do then simply ask.

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, LRow As Long
    Dim chrt As Chart  

    '~~> This is where we will have the chart
    '~~> We declare the object here. Change as applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        '~~. Find the last row in Col A
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Add Chart
        Set chrt = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        With chrt '<~~ Work with chart and set it's parameters
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = ws.Range("N2").Value '<~~ Set the Value here
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Timeline"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Grade"
            .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

            'Formatting
            .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
            .HasLegend = False

            n = 1

            '~~> Add series and set it
            For i = 2 To LRow
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(n).Name = "Progress"
                .SeriesCollection(n).XValues = "=Sheet2!$B$1:$J$1"
                .SeriesCollection(n).Values = "=Sheet2!$B$" & i & ":$J$" & i
                n = n + 1
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much Siddharth Rout - your solution certainly looks more elegant!

Comment: I think that I may have miscommunicated my intentions - I intend to produce various charts, each with only one series on. The code I updated the main post with does this now thanks to your help! I will try to accommodate the LRow idea in - thanks again!

Comment: In that case move the for loop before the `Set chrt = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart` line ;)